# android listview gets inverted on setItemChecked

Tags: android, android-listview

Seemingly in a very odd issue, the list view's order gets inverted when i mark an item as checked using

```
listview.setItemChecked()
```

There is no documentation in the developer docs relating to the same. I appreciate any help.

Here is the code for the check item part

```
CheckBox box = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.select);
box.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view;
        list.setItemChecked(position + list.getHeaderViewsCount(), checkBox.isChecked());

        final long[] checkedItemIds = list.getCheckedItemIds();
        Log.d(Constants.TAG,
                "HomeActivity.onCreate(...).new EMListAdapter() {...}.getView(...).new OnClickListener() {...}.onClick: " + Arrays.toString(checkedItemIds));
        if (checkedItemIds.length > 0) {
            if (mMode == null) {
                mMode = startActionMode(new EashmartActionBar(HomeActivity.this) {
                    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                        menu.add(R.string.delete).setIcon(R.drawable.bin).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
                        return true;
                    }

                    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case 0:
                            Log.d(Constants.TAG,
                                    "HomeActivity.onCreate(...).new EMListAdapter() {...}.getView(...).new OnClickListener() {...}.onClick(...).new EashmartActionBar() {...}.onActionItemClicked: "
                                            + Arrays.toString(checkedItemIds));
                            invoiceManager.delete(checkedItemIds);
                            break;
                        }
                        mode.finish();
                        mMode = null;
                        return true;
                    }

                    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < list.getCount(); i++) {
                            list.setItemChecked(i, false);
                        }
                        mMode = null;
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            if (mMode != null) {
                mMode.finish();
                mMode = null;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The issue seems to be happening only on 2.3 and not on 4.0

Comment: Please describe "gets inverted"...

Comment: inverted as in the first item becomes last, and last becomes first

Comment: Ok, you are right that this is not "normal" behavior. Please post the relevant code so we can see what is happening.

Comment: That code looks fine, so we might need the whole adapter and listactivity/fragment to see whats going on. 
Try create a simple one activity app that replicates the problem.

Comment: when you fill your list, are you using a query thats ordered on checked ?

Comment: @noxius no. The issue seems to vanish if I dont check if the view in getView is null or not.

Answer (score 0):

Don't delete element directly from list.
First remove element from ArrayList of ArrayAdapter.
than recreate/refresh listview with new ArrayList values.

Comment: I am not deleting the item from the list anywhere

Comment: invoiceManager.delete(checkedItemIds);

Comment: That is sending a request to server to delete the item from the database, and removing the item from the adapter.